# setState value in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having problem changing state value in react native. When changing the value of (headerText). It doesn't change in the first call of the method. So it will be showing wrong output. Maybe because the value of (headerText) is based on (index) value which will be changing in the same time? How i can solve it? I need to assign an (index) value then assign (headerText) value

```
    nextRiddle=()=>{

  LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);

  //next riddle
  if(this.state.index < riddle.length-1){
    this.setState({index : this.state.index+1})
    this.setState({headerText : (this.state.index+1)});
  } else {
    this.setState({index : 0}) ;
  }

  //random color
  randomIndexText = 0;
  randomIndexButton = 0;

    while(randomIndexText == randomIndexButton)
      {
        randomIndexText = Math.floor((Math.random() * (colorDark.length-1)));
        randomIndexButton = Math.floor((Math.random() * (colorDark.length-1)));
      }

  this.setState({textBGColor : colorDark[randomIndexText]}) ;
  this.setState({textColor : colorLight[randomIndexText]}) ;
  this.setState({buttonBGColor : colorDark[randomIndexButton]}) ;
  this.setState({buttonColor : colorLight[randomIndexButton]}) ;


  LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
  this.setState({titleFont: 45});


    //animation for riddle text

    if(this.state.animationState==0){

      this.state.textFont = 50
      this.state.animationState =1;
    }else{
      this.state.textFont = 45
      this.state.animationState =0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your issue is caused by the fact that `setState` is async.  You're writing the above code expecting that it's synchronous, which it's not.

In other words, this is what's happening:

```js
this.setState({ foo: 'bar' });
this.state.foo;  // undefined (or some other previous value).
```

And this is what you need to do instead (async):

```js
this.setState({ foo: 'bar' }, () => {
    this.state.foo; // 'bar', what we expect it to be.
});
```

You may have some general problems incorporating it into your existing code, but you need to tap into the second argument of `setState`, which is the callback function.

Comment: While your answer is not wrong it fails to mention that setState can be used to changed multiple properties of the state, like this: `this.setState({textBGColor : colorDark[randomIndexText], textColor : colorLight[randomIndexText], buttonBGColor : colorDark[randomIndexButton], buttonColor : colorLight[randomIndexButton]}) ;`

Answer (score 0):

I just used variables instead of state. and it's working fine.